# Combining booleans using and, or, etc in WPF data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'd like to know if anyone has any suggestions for combining multiple Boolean values using AND, OR, etc in WPF data bindings. Ideally this should be MVVM compliant.

For example:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource DataEntryField-Medium}"
         Text="{Binding FirstName}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsCustomerSelected AND IsEditingEnabled}" />
```

I'd like to have a text box that is only enabled if a customer is selected and editing is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"{Binding IsCustomerSelected AND IsEditingEnabled}" this is not possible in XAML.
We can achieve this by using Multibinding with MultivalueConvertors.

For more info regarding MultiBinding, check [WPF Tutorial - Using MultiBindings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-Multi-binding-and-Multi-value-Conv):

> [Multibinding] enables you to bind to multiple items and return a single new value using a converter. This is extremely useful if a control in your interface needs to be affected by a number of backend property changes.

Answer (score 3):

You also have an option to create composite property in your ViewModel, like this:

```
public bool CanEditCustomer
{
     get { return IsCustomerSelected && IsEditingEnabled; }
}
```

and inside the setters of that properties you should raise PropertyChanged event for that composite property:

```
public bool IsCustomerSelected
{
    ....
    set
    {
        if (value != _isCustomerSelected)
        {
            _isCustomerSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChaged("IsCustomerSelected");
            RaisePropertyChaged("CanEditCustomer");
        }
    }
}
```

and finally xaml:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource DataEntryField-Medium}"
         Text="{Binding FirstName}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding CanEditCustomer}" />
```

This way you do not need a converter, but you have to care about raising PropertyChanged notification in your ViewModel when it is required.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve like so

1. Create MultiValue Converter, here's an example with MarkupExtension that gives You also a possibility to select type of Boolean Logic You want, for test I only implemented AND and OR
   Notice the GetType() check- it's necessary for the Designer to not crash.

```
public class BooleanLogicConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public enum Logic
        {
            And,
            Or
        }
        public Logic Switch { get; set; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }

        public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.FirstOrDefault().GetType().FullName == "MS.Internal.NamedObject")
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    switch (Switch)
                    {
                        case Logic.And:
                            if (value.All(x => (bool)x))
                                return true;
                            else
                                return false;
                        case Logic.Or:
                            if (value.Any(x => (bool)x))
                                return true;
                            else
                                return false;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

2. Use the Converter in the XAML like so

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{conv:BooleanLogicConverter Switch=Or}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.ShowGlobalSettings"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="DataContext.ShowAddModules"/>
</MultiBinding>
```